# Compute cosine without import math in python

Tags: python, while-loop, factorial, trigonometry

I have a general idea of what to do, but my code is a mess and I'm having some trouble writing the algorithm in python for

```
cos(x)=1-(x^2)/2!+(x^4)/4!-(x^6)/6!+...
```

where `x` is in radians, computing `cos(x)` after 20 terms using while loops. So far what I've written is

```
x = float(input("Enter a value for x in degrees."))
x = (x*3.14159)/180
num_of_terms = 0
num = 1.0 ##numerator
y = 1.0
cosx = 1.0

while num_of_terms<1:
    num_of_terms+=1
    cosx = (num/y)
    while num_of_terms>=1 and num_of_terms<=20:
        num_of_terms+=1
        num = num*(x*x)
        y = y*num_of_terms*(num_of_terms-1)
        if num_of_terms%2==0:
            cosx = cosx+(-num/y)
        else:
            cosx = cosx+(num/y)
    print(cosx)
```

I don't know how close I even am to being correct (I know it's wrong in at least some places so I can't properly check using `math.cos`) but the main question I have is how to switch from positive --> negative each term. The assignment states that I cannot use exponentiation operators, and before I was trying to do something like

```
x = float(input("Enter a value for x in degrees."))
x = (x*3.14)/180
num_of_terms = 0
y = 0
z = 1
cosx = ((-1)**(z-1))*((x**z)/(y))
```

so that the sign would switch for every other term. Now I have (as you can see above)

```
if num_of_terms%2==0:
    cosx = cosx+(-num/y)
else:
    cosx = cosx+(num/y)
```

which is incorrect, or at least the output I'm getting is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the sign quite simply:

```
sign = -1
while num_of_terms <= 20:
   sign = -sign
   ...
   cosx += sign * num/y
```

You also have a structure problem in your loops: the first loop will terminate after one iteration ... except you've properly prevented it from getting back there.  This is poor use of a loop.

Just initialize your variables before the loop, and then proceed as expected.  Since you know how many times to iterate, use a **for** instead of a **while**.

```
cosx = (num/y)
for num_of_terms in range(1, 21):
    ...
```

You will find other computational problems in your code.  Print out values each time through the loop to help track your execution and computations.  At the start, just go through 3 or 4 times instead of 20.

For the factorial, keep a running product: it's like a running sum, except that you initialize it at 1, and *multiply* each time through the loop.

---

Okay; stick with the while.  Now, manage your loop index and computational index.  If you're doing term #1, what should the exponent be?  What numbers do you multiply into **y**?  Now identify the same values for term #2 and term #3.

More directly, stick in a print statement to track num_of_terms, y, and cosx.  When you're doing term #3, what is y?  It should be 4! or 6! (depending on how you number your terms), but it's not.  Where did you go wrong?

Comment: I would use a for statement but the assignment explicitly states not to use 'for' statements and to use while statements instead. Thanks for the tip about initializing the variable before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the computation of the factorial. You're multiplying by `num_of_terms`, which only increments by one each time through the loop - you need something that changes by 2 each time through the loop. At least you're correctly multiplying both that number and the number-1.

Comment: Should I replace num_of_terms with y?

Comment: @AxTqka no, that would be wrong. If you stop and think about the problem for a moment, I'm sure the answer will come to you.